# Uploading an image to twitter from website?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter

I want a user to be able to tweet images that are on my site.

First I checked out [Cards](https://dev.twitter.com/cards/getting-started) but the docs say:

> For photos and animated GIFs, upload the media directly with the Tweet or consider using the Twitter API to upload media.

So I check out the [docs](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/uploading-media) and there are ways to do this.

I can't figure out if you are able to upload images from your site using the API, but having them posted by a user's twitter account, won't all of the tweets come from whatever account I set in the script?

Is it possible to let a user upload an image from my site or will I have to use cards?

Comment: typo's in links I think, isn't it?

Comment: Your links don't work.